# Restore one RCP view while restoring another

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Two views in my application need to load same information when restoring state. My idea was, to avoid saving it twice, to have one view create another in `init` or`createPartControl` if it wasn't created yet. However,

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(...)
```

doesn't work there, as `getActivePage()` returns `null`. Is it possible to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate to a manager or service to load/maintain/save the shared state.  That will ensure the first access initializes your information.  When the view is instantiated just go to the manager and retrieve the information.  If the user never instantiates your view, then you never had to do the extra work.

In the general case, you can't create/instantiate one view while creating/activating another view.  Eclipse won't allow it, and will generate ERRORs in the error log.

EDIT:

3 standard persistence patterns I've seen used (and/or misused :-) are:

1) Have your plugin get its state location and simply serialize you state out there. (location provided for free if you subclass `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin`)  You can do it in your activator `stop(BundleContext)` method.  You can uses classes like `org.eclipse.ui.XMLMemento` to serialize to/from XML if you don't already have a solution.

2) if you subclass `org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin` you can use `org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.getDialogSettings()` to store your state.  Potentially a little bulky as you would have to keep it up to date.

3) have your common manager update a preference, potentially using another serialization technique.

Comment: OK. The problem is that with views/editors there is already a useful state persistence system, while I'd have to write a new one separately, so I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: ah, OK.  I'll add to my answer